# Characterization of graphs without leaves

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, trees

Let $G(n,l)$ denote the set of connected graphs with $n$ vertices and $l$ edges and let $G_0(n,l)$ denote the elements of $G(n,l)$ without leaves. It is easily seen that $G_0(n,n-1)$ is empty, since $G(n,n-1)$ is the set of trees, and $G_0(n,n)$ consists of all circular grpahs of length $n$.

**Question:** How can we characterize all elements of $G_0(n,n+1)$ (maybe also $G_0(n,n+2)$) as belonging to some easily described classes of graphs and what would those classes look like? (in analogy to circle graphs for $G_0(n,n)$)

Sorry for the soft question, I guess someone must have already characterized such graphs but I can't find any sources, so I would also be thankful for references to previous work in this direction.

Any help is much apprechiated.

Comment: $G_0(n, n+1)$ should be straightforward: `sage: d = 1; [sum(1 for G in graphs.nauty_geng("%s %s -c" % (n, n+d)) if min(G.degree()) == 2) for n in range(4,13)]` gives $1, 3, 5, 8, 12, 16, 21, 27, 33$ which is $\lfloor(n-2)^2/3\rfloor$, very likely a cycle with a diagonal. or two cycles joined by an edge.  $G_0(n, n+2)$ is probably richer, the numbers are $3, 11, 31, 71, 144, 274, 474, 787, 1241$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of $G_0(n,n+k)$ for $k\geq 1$ can be characterized as follows. Consider any partition $e_1+e_2+\cdots+e_v = 2k$ of $2k$ into $v\leq n$ parts and any multigraph $S$ with $v$ vertices of degrees $2+e_1, 2+e_2, \ldots,2+e_v$ and $v+k$ edges. Then any graph $H\in G_0(n,n+k)$ is obtained by distributing $n-v$ vertices of degree two on the edges of $S$, for a suitable choice of partition and multigraph $S$. The multigraph $S$ is sometimes called the skeleton of $H$. In the case $k=1$, therefore three different multigraphs $S$ occur (pictorially: $\infty$, $\theta$ and $0\!\!-\!\!0$)

Comment: Thank you! It seems $e_1,...,e_v > 0$ is implicitly assumed. Is the number of classes we get then the number of such $S$ modulo graph isomorphism?

Comment: So, the skeleton is obtained by suppressing all vertices of degree two?

Comment: Yes to both questions.